# Hilt injecting child class as parent type

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I have 3 repositories:

```
interface MainRepository {
        ...
    }

interface LocalRepository {
        ...
    }

interface WebRepository {
        ...
    }
```

Each Repository has it's own implementation:

```
@Singleton
class MainRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val localRepository: LocalRepository,
    private val webRepository: WebRepository
) : MainRepository {
...
}

@Singleton
class LocalRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val localMapper: LocalMapper
    private val popularMovieDao: PopularMovieDao
) : LocalRepository {
...
}

@Singleton
class WebRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val webMapper: WebMapper,
    private val popularMovieApi: PopularMovieApi
) : WebRepository {
...
}
```

As you can see, `MainRepository` needs to have both other repositories injected into it, however,I can't really figure out how to do it.

Of course I can inject it with type of `LocalRepositoryImpl` or `WebRepositoryImpl` but I want to inject it with type of `LocalRepository` or `WebRepository` for more generalized approach.

Here is the module that I tried writing:

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
@Module
object Module {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideWebRepository(): WebRepository {
        return WebRepositoryImpl(mapper = WebMapper(), popularMovieApi = PopularMovieApi.getInstance())
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideLocalRepository(): LocalRepository {
        return LocalRepositoryImpl(mapper = LocalMapper(), // Here I can't really 
            // figure out how to get @Dao since it requires DB 
            // which requires context and etc 
            // which makes me think that I've got completely wrong approach to this)
    }
}
```

My Module of LocalData:

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
@Module
object LocalDataSourceModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideMainDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): MainDatabase = MainDatabase.getInstance(context)

    @Provides
    fun providePopularMovieDao(mainDatabase: MainDatabase): PopularMovieDao = mainDatabase.popularMovieDao()
}
```

My Module of WebData:

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
@Module
object RemoteDataSourceModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providePopularMovieApi(): PopularMovieApi = PopularMovieApi.getInstance()
}
```

How do I properly Inject Implementations that I have (`LocalRepositoryImpl` & `WebRepositoryImpl`) while maintaining types of interfaces(`LocalRepository` & `WebRepository)??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`@Binds`](https://dagger.dev/api/latest/dagger/Binds.html). Instead of your `object Module` use following module:

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
@Module
interface Module {

    @Binds
    fun bindWebRepository(repository: WebRepositoryImpl): WebRepository

    @Binds
    fun bindLocalRepository(repository: LocalRepositoryImpl): LocalRepository
}
```

It tells Dagger that if you need `WebRepository` dependency then it must provide `WebRepositoryImpl` and the same for `LocalRepository` and `LocalRepositoryImpl`.

[What is the use case for @Binds vs @Provides annotation in Dagger2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586940/what-is-the-use-case-for-binds-vs-provides-annotation-in-dagger2)

Comment: @Andrew what you mean, `@Binds` do exactly what R'J want. And your solution is no different from manual DI

Comment: No it does not! As R.J said, he doesn't want `WebRepositoryImpl` as his parameters, only `WebRepository`. Therefore, he has to use `@Provides`.

Comment: @Andrew He means parameters in MainRepositoryImpl...

Comment: @Andrew actually, it is needed here

Comment: Between both of your comments I have 2 solutions. @Andrew 's solution is working and he provided a lot of insight. Your solution however is much more concise and works as well, which I definitely prefer.

Answer (score 0):

### Your Repositories

```
interface MainRepository {
        ...
}

interface LocalRepository {
        ...
}

interface WebRepository {
        ...
}
```

### Implementation (No @Inject or @Singleton here!)

```
class MainRepositoryImpl constructor(
    private val localRepository: LocalRepository,
    private val webRepository: WebRepository
) : MainRepository {
...
}


class LocalRepositoryImpl constructor(
    private val localMapper: LocalMapper
    private val popularMovieDao: PopularMovieDao
) : LocalRepository {
...
}


class WebRepositoryImpl constructor(
    private val webMapper: WebMapper,
    private val popularMovieApi: PopularMovieApi
) : WebRepository {
...
}
```

### Di.Module (Repository Module)

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object RepositoryModule {
    
 @Singleton
 @Provides
 fun provideMainRepository(
           localRepository: LocalRepository,
           webRepository: WebRepository
 ): MainRepository = MainRepositoryImpl(localRepository, webRepository)

 @Singleton
 @Provides
 fun provideLocalRepository(
        localMapper: LocalMapper,
        popularMovieDao: PopularMovieDao
 ): LocalRepository = LocalRepositoryImpl(localMapper, popularMovieDao)

 @Singleton
 @Provides
 fun provideWebRepository(
        webMapper: WebMapper,
        popularMovieApi: PopularMovieApi
 ): WebRepository = WebRepositoryImpl(webMapper, popularMovieApi)
```

Try this and tell me if it worked. Since you have provided all your Repositories with `@Provides`, Dagger-Hilt knows how to create them. Are you using `Room` for your localDatabase? If yes, then creating the Database like you did might not be right. If you're not using `Room` that you should start to, as it makes your life easier.

Here is the right way to create a room database with dagger hilt:

### Entity Module

```
@Entity(tableName = "exampleTableName")
data class ExampleEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    // ... whatever you need
    val header: String = "",
    val title: String = "",
    val description: String = "",
)
```

### ExampleDatabase

```
@Database(entities = [ExampleEntity::class], version = 1)
abstract class ExampleDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun exampleDao(): ExampleDao

    companion object {
        const val DATABASE_NAME = "example_db"
    }
}
```

### DAO

```
@Dao
interface DocumentDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(exampleEntity: List<ExampleEntity>)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM exampleTableName")
    suspend fun getList(): List<ExampleEntity>
}
```

### Room Di.Module

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object RoomModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideExampleDB(@ApplicationContext context: Context): ExampleDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(
        context,
        ExampleDatabase::class.java,
        ExampleDatabase.DATABASE_NAME,
    ).fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideExampleDAO(exampleDatabase: ExampleDatabase): ExampleDao = exampleDatabase.exampleDao()

  }
```

Comment: I changing the code as I am writing this. To answer your question - yes, I am using Room, however, not exactly sure what would be the right way to create Database

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm. Also, fixed my Room DB creation. Thanks a lot!