# How to inject a Map using Hilt

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger, dagger-hilt

I have a setup something like this:

```
interface Animal {

}

class Dog @Inject constructor() : Animal

class AnimalProxy @Inject constructor(
    val animalFactory: AnimalFactory,
    val animalMap: Map<AnimalType, Animal>
) : Animal

enum class AnimalType {
    Pet,
    Wild
}
class AnimalFactory @Inject constructor ()
```

And this is how I am binding these object in the module

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class AnimalModule {

    @MapKey
    annotation class AnimalTypeKey(val value: AnimalType)

    @Named(DOG)
    @Provides
    fun provideDog(
    ): Animal {
        return Dog()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @IntoMap
    @AnimalTypeKey(AnimalType.Pet)
    @Named(PROXY)
    fun provideAnimalProxy(
        animalProxy: AnimalProxy
    ) : Animal = animalProxy

    companion object {
        const val DOG = "dog"
        const val PROXY = "proxy"
    }
}
```

But somehow something is not quite right and I am not able to figure out what's going on. I get an error `cannot be provided without an @provides-annotated method`. I know something is wrong when I am creating `provideAnimalProxy` but can't figure it out. Other working option I have is:

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
class AnimalsModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideProxy(
        
    ): Animal {
        return AnimalProxy(
            AnimalFactory(),
            mapOf(
                AnimalType.Pet to Dog(),
            ),
        )
    }
}
```

But this one feels redundant as for `AnimalFactory` I already have an `inject` constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```kotlin
@Named(DOG)
@Provides
fun provideDog(
): Animal {        // Provides @Named(DOG) Animal
    return Dog()   //   which will return a Dog()
}

@Provides
@Singleton
@IntoMap
@AnimalTypeKey(AnimalType.Pet)  // Binds the key Pet
@Named(PROXY)                   // into @Named(PROXY) Map<AnimalType, Animal>
fun provideAnimalProxy(
    animalProxy: AnimalProxy
) : Animal = animalProxy        //   which will return an AnimalProxy()
```

What it sounds like you want is for AnimalProxy to be bound, outside of the map, using its `@Inject` constructor. That would look like this:

```kotlin
@Provides
@IntoMap                       // @IntoMap here means Map<key, Animal>
                               //   because the function returns Animal
@AnimalTypeKey(AnimalType.Pet) // @AnimalTypeKey(Pet) means the key is Pet
                               // Nothing is @Named, so the map isn't named
fun provideDog(
): Animal {                    // Binds Pet into Map<AnimalType, Animal>
    return Dog()               //   which will return a Dog()
}
```

Or, since Dog has an `@Inject` annotated constructor, you can simplify into:

```kotlin
@Provides
@IntoMap
@AnimalTypeKey(AnimalType.Pet)
fun provideDog(dog: Dog): Animal = dog
```

or with [`@Binds`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52618571/1426891), in an abstract class or interface:

```kotlin
@Binds
@IntoMap
@AnimalTypeKey(AnimalType.Pet)
abstract fun bindDog(dog: Dog): Animal
```

For AnimalProxy, you shouldn't use a `@Provides` method for an object you're injecting; if you want `@Singleton` on it you can annotate the AnimalProxy class itself. You can delete that part of the Module entirely.

However, it looks like you might want AnimalProxy to show up in the `Map<AnimalType, Animal>` itself, which sounds like a circular reference: to create the Map you need to create each Animal, including the proxy, which requires creating the same Map you're currently trying to create. If that's the case, you do have a workaround: rather than injecting a `Map<AnimalType, Animal>`, you can [automatically inject](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/multibindings.html#map-multibindings) a `Map<AnimalType, Provider<Animal>>` the same way [you can inject a `Provider<Dog>` rather than just a `Dog`](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/#bindings-in-the-graph). That way you won't express a need for a real AnimalProxy (or its Map) in the constructor, which keeps Dagger from complaining.