# Hilt Android - Why there is a need of @Bind for interface dependency injection when we can perform same thing with @Provide

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

**I have checked all the documentation and knows well that @Binds used for providing interface dependency.But I am bit confused in current example, lets say I have dependency injection for my interface using @Binds in blow code:**

```
interface MyRepository{

}

@Module
abstract class RepositoryModule{

@Binds
abstract fun bindMyRepository(myRepo:MyRepositoryImpl):MyRepository
}

class RegisterUseCase @Inject constructor(private val myRepo:MyRepository)
```

**But the same thing I can also acheive using @Provides**

```
@Module
class RepositoryModule{

@Provides
fun provideMyRepository():MyRepository{

return MyRespositoryImpl()
}
}
```

**We can acheive same goal by using both binds and provides this thing confusing me. Please explain in details so that I can be more clear with my concept about @Binds and @Provides?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586940/what-is-the-use-case-for-binds-vs-provides-annotation-in-dagger2